# Что использовать как back-end для fron-end созданного на React

Tags: php, wordpress, reactjs, frontend, backend

Привет!Я создал fron-end для интернет магазин но теперь мне нужно прикрепить и нему базу и настроить добавление товаров.Можете посоветовать то для этого лучше использовать Php или php с фреймворком,node.js или CMS вроде WordPress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Технологии, используемые для организации backend и frontend не зависят друг от друга. Соответственно, backend можно организовать с любой из упомянутых вами технологий, а также многими другими. Выберите ту технологию, которой вы владеете лучше всего.